# Rails - two queries combining them without SCOPES

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given two queries like:

```
@users1 = Users.find_by_company_id(2)
@users2 = Users.find_by_office_id(2)
```

I want to combine the two:

```
@users_to_show = @users1 + @users2
```

Issue is how how to prevent duplicate users from showing. Is there a way to combine the two (array?) And then ensure that duplicate records are removed?

Thanks

**UPDATED:**

```
# This QUERY gives all of a user's project members, people they work with
@project_ids = @projects.map(&:project_id)

@users = User.find_by_sql [
                            "SELECT DISTINCT users.*
                            FROM users 
                              INNER JOIN permissions ON permissions.user_id = users.id 
                            WHERE project_id IN (?) AND permissions.user_id != ?
                            UNION ALL
                            SELECT DISTINCT users.*
                            FROM users
                            WHERE instance_id = ?",
                            @project_ids, current_user.id, current_user.instance_id
                          ]
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you want to use scopes and save the extra database query?

Comment: I was told not to use scopes, also the queries are pretty complex

Comment: @Tim, just added the two queries. What do you think?

Comment: See in the first queries I want the joins, in the second I do not.

Comment: I think what you need to do is use a UNION ALL type query to combine the two record sets... I'm looking for a Rails way to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a manual SQL approach that may work for you:

```
@users = User.find_by_sql("
     SELECT DISTINCT * FROM USERS WHERE [Place your First complicated where clauses Here]
     UNION
     SELECT * FROM USERS WHERE instance_id = ?
", current_user.instance_id)
```

**EDIT**:
UNION will elimate duplicate records between the two queries.

**EDIT**: Be sure that each of the queries do not produce duplicates independently. Union will not remove duplicates inside single queries.

Comment: Thanks Tim, I think that worked, but I'm not sure yet if that can return duplicate user records... If the same user is returns from both selects, I need to prevent that user from being displayed twice.

Comment: Union should eliminate duplicates.

Comment: I think that should do it! shocking that rails doesn't have a cleaner way to handle this. Thanks Tim

Comment: all of the returned columns must match in order for UNION to detect duplicates.

Comment: Make sure you are also still doing Distinct on the first query.

Comment: @Tim it has it, query pasted above

Comment: Oh wait, is it UNION OR UNION ALL?

Comment: @AmApprentice Remove the ALL from UNION ALL, see my updated answer.